# Install Cloudera without virtual machine/box on windows, Is it possible with any package?

Tags: cloudera-cdh

On windows 2008 R2 server edition, we can not run cloudera on vm. Therefore, finding out an option to install without vm dependency. Can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Cloudera CDH does not support Windows.  If you want to run Hadoop on Windows you should probably look at Hortonworks's HDP 2.0 and higher or follow instructions from the Hadoop wiki [Build and Install Hadoop 2.x or newer on Windows](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows).